# What is the concept behind the "... See more" effect implemented in Facebook iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ios7, uilabel

As you can see in the photo viewer of the Facebook app, there's a 2-liner truncated label (if the text is too long) with a "... See more" at the end. If "See more" is clicked, the whole text is shown with an expanding animation. I just want to know how to achieve, the "... See more" thing and the animations integrated on it.

Answer (score 0):

The "...See More" could be a button. In fact, you can just tap on the same long text, you see a blur effect with text scrolling up.

Before you read more, I would say to watch this [Video](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/problem-arc/BTSCrollView.mov).

This is very well done custom component `BTScrollView`. It is inspired by yahoo weather app.

[`BTScrollView Description`](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/btglassscrollview)
[`BTScrollView Source Code`](https://github.com/BTLibrary/BTGlassScrollView)

You can do little customization or can use this component as it is.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass `UILabel` to do this. Store the actual text somewhere and depending on its size you could display "See More...". You can also add a tap gesture to it(don't forget to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`) and add the animations. This is the simplest way I can think of and probably how it is actually done.